# How can I upload profile pic in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, image-uploading

In add employee form I have to upload profile pic?
is this code is valid??
will anyone help me to modify the code?

This Code Is In My Controller File

```
$employee = new User();
$file = $request->file('file');
$name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('uploads/images', $

$employee->file = $file;
$employee->save();
```

This IS Code Of My view file

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="photo">Profile Picture :<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
      </div>
</div>
```

Issue is that everything work properly but in my collection of mongodb file isn't store. it upload in folder, but not in database.

Comment: have you included enctype="multipart/form-data" wihtin your <form>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `$file` variable with `$name`

```
$employee->file = $name; // $file may contain file object
$employee->save();
```

Comment: for fetching that image in list view i have to right path for that naa?

Comment: @foreach($employees as $empDetail)
     <img src="public/uploads/images/{{ $empDetail->file}}" style="height:100px;">
@endforeach

I have wrote like this, is it correct???

Comment: Remove this `public/` because you must have created virtual host for your project